# For loop iterating through list of variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, python-3.5

I am looking for a way for a `for` loop to be able to iterate through a list of variables and be able to use them as variables like this:

```
>>> a = "original"
>>> b = "original"
>>> c = "original"
>>> d = "original"
>>> for i in [a,b,c,d]:
        i = "change"
>>> print(a,b,c,d)
change change change change
```

Comment: The answer is `exec` if that's actually necessary, but it's highly likely that you don't need that. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Not going to happen. `[a,b,c,d]` is equal to `["original","original","original","original"]`. It has no memory of the variables `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`. Why do you want to do this, anyways? This smells like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I think you should probably elaborate on _why_ you want this.  Given what you've shown so far, I'm tempted to say that it is impossible in python since strings are immutable and python objects are unaware of what names they are bound to ...

Comment: Why are you not using a list, instead of individual variables?  This smells like poor design.  You *could* do it with object **id**s, but that's usually a *bad* idea.

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do, but it's wrong, and you have an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1):

Your initial code does not work because setting the value of "i" does not actually set the value of variables "a", "b", etc.

```
a = "original"
b = "original"
c = "original"
d = "original"
list = [a,b,c,d]
for i in range(0,len(list)):
    list[i] = "change"
print(list)
```

Comment: Using `list` as a variable name masks the built-in function.

Comment: You don't understand, I didn't think that code would actually work, I just used that to show what I wanted to do. @dimab0

Comment: I realize you knew your code would not work. Does this solve what your intention was?

Answer (score 0):

As the comments on the original question point out, this smells a bit and you may want to consider a different way of solving the actual problem.  That being said, here's how you might accomplish what you're trying to do:

```
a = "original"
b = "original"
c = "original"
d = "original"
l = [a, b, c, d]

for idx, val in enumerate(l):
    l[idx] = "change"

print(l)
```

This results in:

`['change', 'change']`

Note that `print(a)` still will result in `original` as [Python strings are immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097994/arent-python-strings-immutable])