# other possible way to duplicate a string from one variable in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I am trying to make a function to duplicate a `string` from one `variable` and returned it with two arguments, what im trying to do is if I type `pie` then it will return `('pie','pie')`, here is what i already do :

```
def duplicateVariabel(kata):
  kata_dua = kata
  return kata,kata_dua
print(duplicateVariabel("aku"))
```

so basically I'm trying to find another way to duplicate `aku` without using `kata_dua = kata` but still return 2 `variables`

Comment: [Python strings are immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097994/arent-python-strings-immutable-then-why-does-a-b-work), if that's what you're worried about.

Answer (score 4):

```py
>>> kata = "kata"
>>> (kata, kata)
('kata', 'kata')
```

No need to create a new variable.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
def duplicateVariabel(kata):
   return kata,kata
print(duplicateVariabel("aku"))
```

`duplicateVariabel` returns the tuple containing the string values.

> so basically im trying to find another way to duplicate aku without using kata_dua = kata but still return 2 variables

Note: Strings in Python are immutabe and variables holds references (they are similar to pointers) to the values/object. So, you aren't basically duplicating the strings. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17246744/5735010).

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246693/what-is-the-difference-between-shallow-copy-deepcopy-and-normal-assignment-oper) for the difference between shallow and deep copy.

```
kata_dua = kata
```

The above statement doesn't do shallow or deep copy. It only copies the reference stored in variable `kata` to `kata_dua` variable. After the above statement, they both point to the same object (for example, `"aku"`)

If you don't believe me, try this:

```
abcd = "abhi"
efgh = abcd
print("ABCD is ", id(abcd))
print("EFGH is ", id(efgh))
```

They both print the same value.

Answer (score 2):

you can simply write `return kata, kata`

just keep in mind, when you return to comma separated variable it returns a tuple. So, access the content accordingly.