# How do I update variable inside string (python)?

Tags: python, string, variables

I have a string like this:

```
Variable = ''

S = """
This is my """+Variable+""" in my string"""

def fun():
    Variable = 'Changed Variable'
    NewS = """
    First sentence. """+S
```

Desired output:

```
  First sentence. This is my Changed Variable in my string
```

What I get now:
First sentence. This is my  in my string

is I put the variable in the string, and then use that as a string, how do I update the variable in that string later?

Comment: You cant. Strings are immuteable. You need to create the full string again. You also use two Variable in different scopes - they do not see each other.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097994/arent-python-strings-immutable-then-why-does-a-b-work

Answer (score 2):

Just use a formatted string or a regular string and add the var to it:

```
string = f"This is my {Variable} in my string"
```