# Change letters in a string in Python

Tags: python

I'm figuring out some basics in python, and somehow I don't get things to work.

```
string = 'water'

string.replace('a','u')

print(string)
```

I want this script to print out wuter. Yet even with the string.replace it still prints out water. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Strings are ***immutable***.

Comment: replace() is an inbuilt function in Python programming language that returns a copy of the string

Comment: Just to complement what previous comments said, I would recommend reading this old but helpful SO question which clarifies what does immutable means: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097994/arent-python-strings-immutable-then-why-does-a-b-work

Comment: Also type `help(string.replace)` and it tells you "Return a copy of S with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new."

Answer (score 2):

```
string.replace('a','u')
```

doesn't change `string`. It returns a new string (which you discard in your case). Try

```
string = string.replace('a','u')
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it done using Regex module substitute

```
import re
my_string = 'water'
my_string2 = re.sub('a', 'u', my_string)
print(my_string2)
```

Comment: Really no need to use `re` module in this case

Comment: Does it really change anything?

Comment: In term of result, no. But I think it's a bad idea to answer with a regex in a case where it is not a good regex case. Because regex can be a performance issue. So short answer: No, long answer in this case: Yes