# How to change an index of a string in a dictionary?

Tags: python, string, dictionary, for-loop, indexing

```
row = {"1":"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"}

for z in range(1,8,3):
    row["1"][z] = "O"
```

I want to change the 1,4, and 7th element of the string to "O"

Comment: What else are you doing with the string? Maybe a different data type would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Python strings are [immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097994/arent-python-strings-immutable-then-why-does-a-b-work). One way to accomplish what you want is to split the string into a list of characters and mutate that:

```
char_list = list(row["1"])
for z in range(1, 8, 3):
    char_list[z] = "O"
row["1"] = "".join(char_list)
```

The new value of `row` will be:

```
{'1': 'aOaaOaaOaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'}
```

Comment: Perhaps:  `"".join("O" if i in range(1, 8, 3) else ch for i, ch in enumerate(row["1"]))`

Answer (score 0):

String are immutable in python, so you can't change it once created. To replace a value at an index, there are several ways of doing it.
One easy way is to create a new string, join values before and after the index

```
row = {"1":"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"}
new_value = "o"

for z in range(1,8,3):
    row["1"] = row["1"][:z] + new_value + row["1"][z+1:]

print(row["1"])
#aoaaoaaoaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

Comment: Note that this method is dangerous as it will change the length of the string if the `range` exceeds the string length (i.e. `range(1, 58, 3)`). It also creates lots of temporary strings and immediately garbage collects them.